# Image disappears when position: absolute

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style the images inside the `li`'s to always stick to the bottom of the div.  But, when I apply `position: absolute` to the images, they disappear. What's the fix for this?

**HTML**

```
<ul id="carousel">
<li class="carousel-img">
    <div></div>
    <img class="defaultImg" src="/design-engine-blue.jpg " style="display: inline-block;">
    <img class="largeImg" src="5/design-engine.jpg" style="display: none;">
   <div class="carousel-title">Design & Engineering</div>
</li>
<li class="carousel-img">
    <div></div>
    <img class="defaultImg" src="/design-engine-blue.jpg " style="display: inline-block;">
    <img class="largeImg" src="5/design-engine.jpg" style="display: none;">
   <div class="carousel-title">Design & Engineering</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```css
#carousel {
    bottom: 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    left: 12.2%;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 980px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;

}

#carousel li {
   float: left;
   height: 223px;
   line-height: 1.7em;
   position: relative;
}

#carousel li img {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    //position: absolute;
    //bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is an element with `id="carousel"`?  Is it the `<ul>`?

Comment: Yes - I just added it to the question.

Comment: Please show your HTML. Also are you using an open source carousel? If so, which one?

Comment: Have you tried adding a `z-index` to your element with a position absolute? It could be simply hidden behind your element. Also try using position `top`, it could give some context to the cause of the disappearance.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4QhDf/). I wasn't sure on how the images were supposed to be styled, but in this example you can see them, even if they are set to `position: absolute;`.

Comment: Actually, removing overflow: auto from #carousel fixed that problem.  But now I have another issue, the second image inside the 2nd li is being hidden behind the first and only only image is being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Here we have a [great example of this issue - jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f0u9xfb1/)

You need to set the `position` on that image as `relative`. Although some designer freak could probably explain it better.